# Same View for landscape and Portrait in Splitview

Tags: ipad, uisplitviewcontroller

I want same view in portrait and landscape in splitview in iPad Application. In portrait I get rootviewcontroller as popOver. I don't want that. It should be same as it is displayed in landscape mode. Is it possible?

Comment: In portrait i get rootviewcontroller as popOver. I don't want that. It should be same as it is displayed in landscape mode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I'm afraid that the term **same** is a bit confusing here. There is no problem for you to develop a **similar** view, but evidently with other size and proportions. You can perfectly dismiss the popover on the portrait mode, and compose your new view with a tableview controller at the left side of the screen.

Comment: Thought of that. Got another concept of custom splitview. Have to work upon that. Hope that will work. Thanks for replying. :)